# Using HasJsonRelationships from staudenmeir in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have a column called operators which is a json array that looks like this `[1, 2, 3]`. The numbers are ids on the operators table. Now how can I use the HasJsonRelationships to get the operators. I have only found one way to use this with objects in an array.

I tried this:

```php
public function operators(): HasManyJson
{
    return $this->hasManyJson(Operator::class, 'operators[]');
}
```

UPDATE:

Tried following

```php
public function operators(): HasManyJson
{
    return $this->hasManyJson(Operator::class, 'operators[]->id');
}
```

Error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'operators.operators' in 'where clause'

```sql
select * from `operators` where (1 member of(json_extract(`operators`.`operators`, '$[*]."id"')))
```

and

```php
public function operators(): HasManyJson
{
    return $this->hasManyJson(Operator::class, 'operators');
}
```

Error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'operators.operators' in 'where clause'

```sql
select * from `operators` where (1 member of(`operators`.`operators`))
```

Comment: You don't need to call them as `operators[]`, should work using just `operators`

Comment: or try to operators[]->id

Comment: Unfortunately, neither works.